# How can I convert MySQL date stored as negative (signed) bigint to date format?

Tags: mysql, datetime, bigint

I have birth dates stored in a MySQL database that I need converted to a readable date format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. I cannot use the MySQL's From_Unix function as many birth dates are before 1970 and the function returns `NULL`. (i.e. -866138400000 which is 07/21/1942)

I have tried to use ticks but that is also returning `NULL`:

```
(FROM_DAYS(365 + (req.PATIENTDOB / 864000000000)) + INTERVAL (req.PATIENTDOB % 864000000000) / 10000000 SECOND) AS ptDob
```

Any advance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: so the value is still stored as microseconds since 1970. and negative values mean before 1970. just writing it down because it took me a second to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you're making things so complicated. Just divide by 1000 to get seconds instead of microseconds and subtract that from 1970-01-01.

```
mysql > select '1970-01-01' + interval -866138400000/1000 second;
+---------------------------------------------------+
| '1970-01-01' + interval -866138400000/1000 second |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1942-07-22 06:00:00                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So your query would actually be this of course:

```
select '1970-01-01' + interval your_column / 1000 second from your_table;
```

This query proves, that your assumption, that it would be 1942-07-21 is wrong. 1942-07-22 is correct.

```
mysql > select timestampdiff(second, '1942-07-21', '1970-01-01');
+---------------------------------------------------+
| timestampdiff(second, '1942-07-21', '1970-01-01') |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                         866246400 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer while researching Negative Epochs. I was able to use the From_Unixtime function after all!

`select date_format((DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(0), interval -866138400000/ 1000 second)),'%Y-%m-%d') as ptdate;`
-> "1942-07-21"

Link to [Reference](https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql#negavtiveEpoch) > Look under Negative Epochs section